# VBA code to click on each View Contact tabs using selenium VBA

Tags: vba, selenium, firefox

In webpage there are 10 View Contact tabs having the same name(View Contact).I am trying to click on each View Contact tabs using selenium VBA but i am able to click only 1st View Contact using below Selenium VBA code but Internet explorer code working fine but i want to click each tabs using selenium vba code.

My Selenium VBA code:-

```
Dim ele As WebElement
For Each ele In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//input[@value='View Contact']")
ele.Click
Next
```

My Internet explorer code:-

```
With ie.document
Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("input")
For Each e In elems
       If (e.getAttribute("value") = "View Contact") Then
           e.Click
           'Exit For
       End If
    Next e
End With
```

My Html code:-All 10 Tabs are having the same html code

```html
<input type="button" class="boxOpener btn blue b" style="width: 150px;font-size: 14px;" value="View Contact">
```

Comment: Can you provide the html? What happens to the page when you click a contact tab?

Answer (score 0):

To click on each **`View Contact`** through **`Selenium`** you can use the follwing code block :

```
Dim ele As WebElement
For Each ele In driver.FindElementsByXPath("//input[@class='boxOpener btn blue b' and @value='View Contact']")
    ele.Click
Next ele
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using this code i am able to click only one tab but i want to click all 10 tabs

Comment: Does `View Contact` page open in the same `TAB/Window` or separate `TAB/Window`?

Comment: same TAB/Window

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this:

```
Dim elem as Object
For Each elem In IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")
    If InStr(elem.Value, "View Contact") > 0 Then elem.Click: Exit For
Next elem
```